# Ejecting a USB Drive

Tags: c#, c++

I am following the [CodeProject Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/375916/How-to-Prepare-a-USB-Drive-for-Safe-Removal) to remove a USB drive in C#. the issue I am facing is the USB Pen Drive eject successfully but doesn't works on a portable hard drive. code is given below

```
int r = CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi(DevInstParent, IntPtr.Zero, null, 0, 0);
LogFile.Err("Eject Return value - " + r);
```

When a USB pen drive is forced to eject the integer r returns 0 and eject command is successful, but when a portable drive is forced to eject, it returns 23.

Comment: Depending on if that's 23 in dec or hex, the return is either `CR_REMOVE_VETOED` or `CR_NO_MORE_HW_PROFILES`, probably the former. In the code you linked there is an enum `PNP_VETO_TYPE`, which I would look at to see why the veto is occuring.

Comment: life is too short for safely remove USB ;)

Comment: @silver yap but I am ejecting it right after insertion, means without doing any operation on USB

Comment: @tjennings this seems to be CR_REMOVE_VETOED

Comment: Instead of calling `CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi`, call `CM_Request_Device_Eject` using an `out` parameter for the second parameter, which should inform you of the Veto Reason. The NoUi method does not pass back the Veto Reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to cfgmgr32.h, 23 (0x17) is `CR_REMOVE_VETOED`, suggesting that the OS is overruling your attempt to remove the drive. Looking at the code you've linked, `CM_Request_Device_Eject_NoUi` is just calling `CM_Request_Device_Eject` without using an `out` parameter for `pVetoType`, so your Veto Reason is being discarded without informing you.

Adjust your code to show you the value of `pVetoType`. You will almost certainly need to find a copy of cfgmgr32.h's source code to know what the returned value signifies. That information will be necessary for any furthur debugging.